# How to remove duplicate object in array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a VC where I fetch data for only the 1st object in an array of objects. so I only fetch `arrayOfObjects[0]` then when I enter a second VC I need to fetch all the other data associated with the other objects in that same array. But then I have a problem where I end up fetching that first bit of data I already had again. So my array would look like, `data1, data1, data2, data3 ...` which is not what I want of course.

Currently what I had tried to fix this issue, was to do the following: `MainObject?.arrayOfSubObjects.remove(at: 0)`, this however means that on the first go it works well, but every time I go back to the preceding VC and then back I subtract one of the objects that I want to be there. So I end up with: `data2, data3 ...`

**So my question is how can I remove that extra object from the beginning, but not delete anything after its been deleted?**

Some things i have tried:

```
            if selectedPost?.media[0].videoURL != nil {
            if selectedPost?.media[0].videoURL == selectedPost?.media[1].videoURL {
                selectedPost?.media.remove(at: 0)
            } else {
                print("NO!!!!!! they are not the same ")
            }

        } else if selectedPost?.media[0].image != nil {
            if selectedPost?.media[0].image == selectedPost?.media[1].image {
                selectedPost?.media.remove(at: 0)
            } else {
                print("NO!!! they are not the same ")
            }

        }
```

This however does not do anything, it always ends up going into the else. I have also tried stuff like setting number schemes, but this failed because the VC kept reloading

Comment: Your approach should not be removing it once it’s duplicated. Instead it should never appending it again.

Comment: Yes that woudl eb optimal but how shoudl I go about doing that? I will think about that now and delete this comment if I make it work

Comment: Show your fetch code. Maybe I can help with that

Comment: check teh updated quetsion @GaloTorresSevilla

Comment: Please also add your Media struct or class. Best way for you will be to conform to Hashable and have an identifier to make the comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do it like this:

```
guard let selectedPost = selectedPost else { return }
if selectedPost.media.contains(where: {$0.image == image}) { return } // Here the $0.image should be replaced with $0.mediaURL == mediaURL for the videos or however you videoURL is called in Media
selectedPost.media.append(Media(image: image, timeStamp: Double(timeStamp)))
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Try conforming `Hashable` in you `Media` class:

```
class Media : Hashable {


    var hashValue : Int {
        return image.hashValue
    }

    var image = UIImage()
    // .....

    static func == (lhs: Media, rhs: Media) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }

}
```

Then you can compare two media objects with `==`, So you can do something similar to the top part of this answer. Good luck

Comment: on:                     if selectedPost.media.contains(where: {$0 == mediaURL}) { return }
I get : Extraneous argument label 'where:' in call, even though I dont get this when I do it for images

Comment: So It came out weird, the first time it still had teh same problem and then every time I returned that first data kept on getting duplicated untill at one point when I returned it duplicated other media as well.

Comment: No in the media class there, when it comes to images, is only (of course there is an init to bring in teh appropriate data) a var image : UIImage, I con vert the mediaURL into data and then into a UIImage and pass it in in the fetch function (convertMediaDataIntoMediaFormatAndAddToMedia())

Comment: Before I post that... What is hashable? and what would it do?

Comment: Ok. No worries if you cannot post it. I'll add an example in the answer

Comment: How do I go about using teh ==?

Comment: you can now compare 2 Media objects with `==`

Comment: what is the sintax for that? I tried:                     if !((selectedPost?.media[0].hashValue) != nil) == selectedPost?.media[1].hashValue {
 but get : Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Bool' and 'Int?'

Comment: `if selectedPost?.media.contains(where: {$0 == newMedia}) { return }`

Comment: why? `if !(selectedPost?.media.contains(where: {$0 == Media(image: image, timeStamp: Double(timeStamp))}))! { return }` if it is true it should return, not if it is false. Remove the first `!`

Comment: ok so I got rid of it. And when I ran it the first VC I was in, still duplicated had the first duplicate like before. Then when I whent into another VC I kept going in and out. The first time I entered it was as it should be, but then every time I left and came back it woudl duplicate all teh data in the VC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187615/discussion-between-galo-torres-sevilla-and-nebur-rb).

Comment: Could you check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54454445/how-to-add-completion-blocks-to-my-firebase-calls-to-avoid-media-duplication

Comment: hey so I have changed my DM so now I only fetch once in a VC and then go into a second one with data I had sorted and sort it into a post object and media objects. I do teh above thing but it does not seem to do anything and I dont see how it would have to do with asyncronys calls